# How to make it so that the children elements will never wrap to the next line even though the parent element's width may be small for them?

Tags: css

How to make it so that the children elements will never wrap to the next line even though the parent element's width may be small for them? I want them to be overflowed (e.i. overflow: hidden). I need this for a photo preview system (thumbnails) I am building. Currently the children elements are left-floated.

Comment: Can you supply the HTML and CSS for the elements in question?

Answer (score 2):

I found a generic solution in a forum. [Link to the answer](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/627827-how-wrap-text-css#post3634888)

And as Dan said, we would need to see the HTML and CSS for this..